# How to pass driver parameters via dkms?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers

I am trying build/install a driver via dkms.  I have successfully started the driver with its default parameters but not sure how to add optional params?

For example to install the driver using insmod I can specify an arg such as:

```
insmod ./rp2.ko polling_mode=0
```

with dkms I create a dkms.conf

```
PACKAGE_NAME="rp2"
PACKAGE_VERSION="2.18"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
MAKE[0]="make"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="rp2"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/kernel/drivers/tty"
```

then steps

1. dkms add rp2/2.18
2. dkms build rp2/2.18
3. dkms install rp2/2.18

Adding the arg to the dkms install command is unrecognized

Answer (score 0):

it looks like I can add an options file into /etc/modprobe.d/rp2.conf

```
options rp2 polling_mode=0
```